# does shared preferences have a fail safe behavior?

Tags: android

What is happening if I write a value to shared preferences and while the async apply is pending, the app gets interrupted. ( either sigterm or a crash) is the date still the old or did the data get corrupted?
As I saw the commit does a sync write and reports about the result, but when does the commit return a false? how do we get there? If the thread gets shut down by a crash, we won't be able to notice any failure of the commit.